# Get transaction details using transaction id

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How to get transaction details using transaction id ?

I tried generate access token and then tried to get transaction details.But its showing me INVALID_RESOURCE_ID

To generate access token :

```
curl -v​ https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "EOJ2S-Z60oN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EC1usMEUk8e9ihI7ZdXLF5cz6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp"
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

To get transaction details :

```
$access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/<TXN_ID>");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' .$access_token,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$result = json_decode($response);
print_r($result);exit;
```

Response :

```
stdClass Object ( [name] => VALIDATION_ERROR [details] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [field] => #/id [location] => body [issue] => INVALID_RESOURCE_ID ) ) [message] => Invalid request - see details [information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#error-VALIDATION_ERROR [debug_id] => 447f920460e84 )
```

I would like to know how can i get transaction details using transaction id in sandbox mode  ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you provide a invalid resource id in your request.

I recommend to use the official PayPal PHP SDK. You can download it here:
[PayPal-PHP-SDK Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) and there is a good example for getting a transaction [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/OrderGet.php)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i am not using php sdk.I am using this code inside api.Mobile app using android/ios sdk then entire response is pass to API.
Inside API functions i would like to confirm that response coming from mobile app is correct or not.

Comment: Regarding security notice, Thanks for notify but i had copied from paypal page. And its not right credentials of client so no need to worry.https://www.paypal.com/md/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-get-an-access-token-ts2128

Comment: The api says you don´t provide a correct transaction id, so you may check that first. Best to try it manually via postman for example (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-postman/)

Comment: I had confirmed that transaction id is same as i getting from paypal.Because mobile app is not modifying transaction id. Then why its showing that incorrect transaction id ? I am able to create access token

Comment: Did you try to get the transaction via postman as well? What is the output there?

Comment: You as well can try to fetch it via command line: `curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"` as referenced [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get)